# How can i set "worklight_enc_password" for WL 6.2 local development server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I need to test for worklight.properties encrypted variables. I only find a doc for setting real WAS worklight server. But no doc mentions about the local testing server that shipped from WL studio.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is adding a server.env file to the server directory. And put the var inside.

Detail:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21596484

Answer (score 0):

You should use the guide you've found, as there should be no difference...

WAS = WebSphere Application Server
Liberty = WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile

Liberty is a type of WAS.

To be sure, verify you are following the second option provided in the following user documentation topic: [Storing properties in encrypted format](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_storing_properties_in_encrypted_format.html?lang=en)

Comment: For WAS, i can set the env var inside WAS web console. But for the local Liberty, where can i set that? Inside jvm.options? server.xml?

Comment: I would imagine you do this in server.xml